# David was 30 years old when he became king. Jesus was 30 when he started public ministry. Coincidence?

Tags: luke, 2-samuel

2 Samuel 5:4
New International Version

> David was **thirty** years old when he became king, and he reigned forty years.

Luke 3:23

> Now Jesus himself was about **thirty** years old when he began his ministry. He was the son, so it was thought, of Joseph, the son of Heli

What is the significance of this connection and the fact that their ages are mentioned explicitly in the Scripture?

Comment: In scripture, twenty is the age at which one becomes physically able to participate in combat (Exodus 38:26; Leviticus 27:3-5; Numbers 1:20-22, 32:11; 2 Chronicles 25:5). As you are probably well aware, up until very recently, in many countries, including my own, military service was mandatory, and, in many others, it still is. What would have been the point of getting a stable job, or starting a family, before that age ?

Comment: @Lucian Because there were no standing armies and people didn't live in suburbs with atomic families. The age of marriage was early teenage years. By the time you reached twenty, the kids were weaned and extended family cared for them if by chance you went off to fight a war. However 30 was a special age of maturity. That was the age when man is considered in his prime.

Comment: @Robert: *The age of marriage was early teenage years.* - For women. Not for males, who had to suport the entire household. Even today, despite the annihilation of many differences, men still marry at an older age then women.

Comment: @Lucian This is just false. The Bar Mitzvah was the age at which you could marry by tradition. For other cultures, see the literature. Of course men married at many ages, especially rich men who would marry young women. But young men generally married long before military service in arranged marriages as part of larger kinship structures. Males did not support households all by themselves, these were not atomic families.

Comment: @Robert: Males married at older ages long before atomic families became the norm. Bottom line, not having been born into a royal family, there was no other way for him to rise to power, except by first proving himself on the battlefield, which technically he did a few years before fully coming of age (1 Samuel 17:14+).

Comment: Seriously, @Lucian, this is not up to debate. A small number of rich men married at older ages because they had multiple wives and were the heads of clans.  They were patriarchs. But the average male was not a patriarch, he was part of a clan headed by a patriarch and was in an arranged marriage and had only one wife that he married in his early teen years. There is a very small chance that he would be a patriarch himself and then be able to collect women well into his old age, like David or Solomon. The examples of Kings or Patriarchs like Abraham were not typical situations for marriage.

Comment: @Robert: Not sure what polygamy has to do with this; Roman soldiers married by the time they satisfied their military service and became veterans; there is a reason the word widower comes from a feminine noun, and not the other way around, as is usually the case. After the inevitable demise of the father, the older brothers would take care of their elderly mother, as we see even in the Gospels, with Mary and His (older) brothers following Christ around (Matthew 12:46-49; Mark 3:31-34; Luke 8:19-21; John 2:12; Acts 1:14).

Comment: Jesus probably wasn't exactly 30 - if he was born in 5-6 BC and he died in AD 30 or AD 33, then if he had a 3 year public ministry he would've been between 32 and 36.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the age of thirty is not difficult to find.  As Messiah, Jesus was:

- **King** of the spiritual kingdom of Israel (Luke 1:33, John 1:49, Acts 13:23, Rev 11:15)and thus the Son of David and the fulfillment of the Davidic covenant (Matt 1:1-16, compare 2 Sam 7, Ps 61:7, Isa 9:7, Ps 146:10)
- **Prophet** as prophesied in Deut 18:15, 17-19 as noted in Acts 3:22, 23.
- **Priest**, more particularly, High Priest of the Christian Covenant as stated many time is places like, Heb 4:14-16, 5:10, 7:23-28, 8:1, 2, 9:1-28, 10:1-18.

As the holder of this triple title of Prophet, Priest and King, Jesus needed to fulfill the OT requirements.

- As a prophet, he was set apart from birth as were Isaiah 49:1, 5, Judges 13:7, 16:17, Ps 22:10, Jeremiah 1:5
- As a King and Son of David, Jesus began His ministry at age 30 when He was baptized just as David did, 2 Sam 5:4.
- As a Priest, Jesus began His ministry at age 30 as did the priests of ancient Israel, Num 4:1, 23, 30, 35, 39, 43, 47, as was Jesus in Luke 3:23.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. As imitators of Christ, we too are prophets (messengers of the Bible), priests (1 Pet. 2:9), and royalty ("*royal priesthood*", "holy nation for God's own possession"). +1.

Comment: @Xeno - great point but I did not want to clutter the answer by straying too far from the question.

Answer (score 0):

The lord was about thirty infact he was thirty-one because he died at thirty-tree infact his preaching was about one year. So the connection with the David age Is on the number 3 and not 30.

Answer (score -1):

> What is the significance of this connection and the fact that their ages are mentioned explicitly in the Scripture?

None.

> Coincidence?

Yes.

Comment: Even though I agree with you, if you're going to write an answer you need to provide justifying evidence.